# Axon Framework read all events from domain_event_entry table, and not to serialize payload in it

Tags: java, spring-boot, axon

I am using Axon Framework without Axon Server and with Spring Boot auto configuration. 
I have an H2 database, using the Spring auto configuration.

It seem like the `EventStore` API only provide the `EventStore#readEvents(String aggregateId)` method, to read all events for a specific aggregate.
However, I would like to read all events, fron all aggregates.

How can I achieve this?

And secondly, I don't want to serialize the data in the payload, I want to store it in JSON, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you need this functionality for @polosoft? Or, differently put, what's the use case to access the `EventStore` API directly to retrieve all the events, if Axon has a perfectly fine annotation based Event Handler solution to do just that?

Comment: I want to search in the domain_event_entry table, that's why i dont want to serialize the data.

Comment: I understand you want to search it, that's why you're asking the question in the first place I assume. But, _why_ do you need to search it?

Comment: This is what our client asked, for some reasons they want to know what could a user saw on the tables, for example I have to tell our client today what could a user do, and see in 2015.

Comment: Wouldn't giving them access to the database directly do the trick? Anyhow, as pointed out this will require some custom work from your part.

Another thing you could think about, is setting up Axon Server.
The "search" window in Axon Server's dashboard shows the entire list of events, in serialized format, out of the box. You'd thus effectively have a "all events"-view for free if you would set it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EventStore` interface itself indeed only contains methods to read events for a given Aggregate. 
That interface however implements the `StreamableMessageSource` interface (which you can find [here](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/74267bd4ff107a2ca391eebc7b150744c6500639/messaging/src/main/java/org/axonframework/messaging/StreamableMessageSource.java)).

Through this interface, the `EventStore` provides you the `openStream(TrackingToken)` method. The `TrackingToken` specifies at which point in the stream you want to start.
As a short cut, if you provide `null` as the `TrackingToken`, the stream will open at the beginning of time (for said event stream of course).

Note though, that I would typically suggest against querying the `EventStore` directly.
Axon provides a perfectly fine annotation based approach to handling events, by drafting up an `@EventHandler` annotated method in an Event Handler class you register to the store (something which is done automatically for you when using Spring Boot auto configuration).

As a short hand to read **all** events in a single Event Handling Function, you can do the following:

```java
@EventHandler
public void on(Object event) {
    // Perform event handling logic
}
```

In this snippet, I am performing somewhat of a trick.
Axon will by default provide an Event to the most specific implementation of said event.
As everything in Java implements `Object`, simply having a single Event Handler where the first parameter (note that the first parameter is *always* the Event payload) is of type `Object` will do the trick.

---

Now for the last question you've posted (I would suggest to make separate question for this in the future to keep focus on Stack Overflow):

> And secondly, I don't want to serialize the data in the payload, I want to store it in JSON, how can I do that?

Do you mean you want to handle the event as JSON in an Event Handler?
Or, that you want to retrieve a stream of JSON from the `EventStore` directly?
Note that it's impossible to store the objects as is, so serialization will **always** take place.

If it's disabling deserialization, then I can tell you that you'll have to query the actual database yourself for this, or heavily customize the `EventStorageEngine` (the storage engine is what the `EventStore` uses to retrieve events from your database).
The AxonIQ team is thinking of adding just such a feature, but I can assure you that this hasn't been implemented yet.

Hope this clarifies your options @polosoft!

Comment: Dear Steven! Thanks for your support. I will have several questions in the future about Sagas, please if you will have time answer it.

Comment: I am monitoring any Axon related questions, so chances are high I will pick them up any how. ;-)

Comment: @Steven I am using axon server and built a command and query microservices. But, whenever I am restarting the microservices than it is [rocessing all the events available in the event store. I want to query and command to not process already processed events even after any number of start. I have read about TracingToken but I am unable to get as to how it works. Can you please help me with this asap? I have a deadline to finish this.

Comment: I would recommend to create a new issue for this, @upadhyayRakes. Know that although it's troublesome you are having a deadline, that's not per say my concern when it comes to answering your question. I am very willing to help mind you, but if you are under time pressure I would suggest not to use a free forum solution like StackOverflow, but contact a company (AxonIQ for example) directly.